# Concise way of outputting newlines in C#

Tags: c#, .net

In C++, I can do this:

```
cout << "Line 1\nLine 2\n";
```

In Java, I can do this:

```
System.out.printf("Line 1%nLine 2%n");
```

In C#, do I really need to do one of these cumbersome things:

```
Console.WriteLine("Line 1");
Console.WriteLine("Line 2");
```

or

```
Console.Write("Line 1{0}Line 2{0}", Environment.NewLine);
```

or is there a more concise way, which is not platform-specific?

Comment: Is `\n` in C++ platform-agnostic? As far as I know that represents a linefeed character which is a valid Unix newline but not a complete Windows newline (it's `\r\n`), but I'm ignorant when it comes to C++.

Comment: Um, Java and C# have the same amount of characters for printing something out. Why are you calling C# cumbersome but not Java?

Comment: In any case, outputting `\r\n` could work, as `\n` is still part of it and will therefore be recognized as a newline on Unix systems.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answers so far. Just to confirm my requirements: I am not targeting a specific platform, it must be platform-agnostic. And in answer to the above comments: yes in C++ \n is platform-agnostic because the underlying class methods will convert the \n to \r\n on platforms where such a conversion is appropriate. And no, Java and C# don't have the same amount of characters for printing something out, in Java you can use the printf method which recognises "%n" as the platform-dependent line terminator, whereas in C# you have to write Environment.NewLine or something similar.

Comment: Oh one more comment, although \r\n would work on Unix and \n would work on Windows (because the normal console window is ok with it) I want to be able to redirect the output to a file, and I don't want vi on Unix to show me extraneous carriage returns at the end of each line, nor do I want Notepad on Windows to show me funny characters just because there is no \r before the \n.

Comment: @Klitos I've provided a concise way to do it in my answer. Have a look. If you're using .NET 3.5, then you'll be able to do this and get (almost) the same conciseness you would in C++.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no concise, platform-agnostic, built-in newline placeholder in C#.

As a workaround, you could create an extension method for `Environment.NewLine`

```
public static class StringExtensions()
{
    public static string NL(this string item)
    {
        return item += Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `NL` (picked because of brevity)

```
Console.Write("Hello".NL());
Console.Write("World".NL());
```

writes out:

```
Hello
World
```

You could also make an extension method that simply writes out something to the console.

```
public static void cout(this string item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    //Or Console.Write(item + Environment.NewLine);

}
```

And then:

```
"Hello".cout();
```

Comment: Using your method in his original example...

Console.WriteLine("Line 1".NL() + "Line 2".NL());

It's still not as concise as his original examples in other languages.

Comment: @RickL Did you see my solution at the bottom? It's as concise as C++ (`.cout()`) vs. `cout <<`). Not to mention my first solution is far more concise than the present implementation (if you have to write out `Environment.NewLine` a lot.

Comment: Thanks George, nice idea, but I don't see how "Hello".cout() can accommodate the equivalent of cout << "Hello\nWorld\n"; wouldn't you have to do something like ("Hello".NL() + "World").cout() which is a bit longer to write than in C++? The issue I'm asking about is not the length of Console.WriteLine vs. cout, but the length of Environment.NewLine vs. "\n".

Comment: @Klitos you can create an extension method for each way you want to do it. If You want to create a custom separator and create an extension method that inserts a `Environment.NewLine` for that, then do so.  My point is: Extension methods can solve this 'problem' for you.

Answer (score 3):

This *should* work:

```
Console.Write("Line 1\r\nLine 2");
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

```
Console.Write("Line 1\nLine2");
```

Depending on the environment you may need to use `\r\n`.

Comment: Exactly, OP is looking for a platform-agnostic solution other than `Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, `Environment.NewLine` will just return "\r\n". So in your code you could do

```
Console.Write("Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\n");
```

Or simply

```
Console.Write("Line 1\nLine 2\n");
```

still works on most platforms. But otherwise you'll have to use the `Environment.NewLine`, or another similarly implemented and shorter named method, to return the correct string.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, I think you are right, to ensure it works correctly on ALL platforms I'll need to use Environment.NewLine. Which is slightly disappointing as Java has the "%n" directive in its string formatter methods whereas C# doesn't seem to have, even though it can be argued to be nicer than Java in many other ways.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would recommend creating an extension method on the Console class, but that's not possible since Console is static.  Instead, you could create a ConsoleHelper:

```
public static class ConsoleHelper
{
    public static void EnvironmentSafeWrite(string s)
    {
        s = Environment.NewLine == "\n" ? s : s.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write(s);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ConsoleHelper.EnvironmentSafeWrite("Line 1\nLine 2\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Console.WriteLine() will simply output a newline without requiring other text.

You can change the defined string for NewLine by setting `Console.Out.NewLine = "your string here";`

Answer (score 1):

`\r\n` Can be used on Windows platforms. However you question doesn't state which platform you are targeting. If you want your code to be multi-platform and future proof is probably safer to use `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Thanks. I do want to be multi-platform and future-proof. However, I was looking for something a bit more concise than having to use a separate string constant such as Environment.NewLine as I have a number of closely-related strings to output on separate lines and wanted to do it all with a single Write call.

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer yet another workaround:

With [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#string-interpolation) (C# 6.0 and above), you can use

```
Console.Write($"Line 1{Environment.NewLine}Line 2{Environment.NewLine}");
```

Unfortunately, you can't define a constant for `Environment.NewLine` with a short name, since `Environment.NewLine` is not constant, but you can use a `static readonly` property as the next best thing:

```
private static readonly string NL = Environment.NewLine;

...

void someMethod()
{
    ...
    Console.Write($"Line 1{NL}Line 2{NL}");
    ...
}
```